# Change in order of integration

Tags: integration

I have this equation, $$\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}(x) \, dx \, dy$$ and, I want to change the order of integration from $dx\,dy$ to $dy\,dx$.$\text{ }y$ varies from $y=-a \text{   to  }y=a$, and $x\text{  varies from }x=0 \text{ to } x=\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$. When we change the order of integrals, I understand

$ y = \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \text{ (to) }  -\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, but its said that $x = 0 \text{ to } a$

am not getting why the limits of x should vary from 0 to a instead of 0 to $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$?

-Kamal.

Comment: Draw a picture of the (x,y)-domain of integration.

Answer (score 1):

You are integrating over the semi-circle of radius $a$ and center $O(0,0)$ in the plane with $x \ge 0$. Draw a figure. Now, to get the new limits of integration, interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$. $x$ should move between $0$ and $a$. Where should $y$ move?

Comment: I feel some where its going wrong! because after change of integrals, I get $$\frac{-2}{3}a^\frac{3}{2}$$, but book says $$\frac{2}{3}a^3$$ and the original integrals produces $$\frac{-1}{3}a^3$$

Comment: I got the answer thanks for all your help.